# Java-How to translate a String to piglatin?

Tags: java, string, character

I am writing a pig latin code and I am tripped up by how to get my program to identify where the next vowel in the word is if the first letter in the word is a consonant. Then it moves the first part of the word, up to the first vowel, to the end of the word and prints ay along with it. (ex. trees = eestray)

This is the code I have now

```
// word is bringing in the string entered from the user
public static void translate(String word) {

    String wordCap, pigLatin = "";
    char vowels;
    int lowest = 0, tempOne, tempTwo, tempThree, tempFour, tempFive;  

    wordCap = word.toUpperCase();
    vowels = wordCap.charAt(0);

    if (vowels == 'A' || vowels == 'E' || vowels == 'I' || vowels == 'O' || vowels == 'U') {
            word = word + "way";
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        else {
            tempOne = wordCap.indexOf('A', 1);
            if (lowest > tempOne && tempOne != -1) {
                lowest = tempOne;
            }
            tempTwo = wordCap.indexOf('E', 1);
            if (lowest > tempTwo && tempTwo != -1) {
                lowest = tempTwo;
            }
            tempThree = wordCap.indexOf('I', 1);
            if (lowest > tempThree && tempThree != -1) {
                lowest = tempThree;
            }
            tempFour = wordCap.indexOf('O', 1);
            if (lowest > tempFour && tempFour != -1) {
                lowest = tempFour;
            }
            tempFive = wordCap.indexOf('U', 1);
            if (lowest > tempFive && tempFive != -1) {
                lowest = tempFive;
            }




public static char vowel(String word) {
    int start= 0, end= 0;
    char vowels;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        vowels = word.charAt(i);
        if (vowels == 'A' || vowels == 'E' || vowels == 'I' || vowels == 'O' || vowels == 'U') {
            end = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return (char) end;
}
```

(in translate method)

```
for (int i = 0; i<wordCap.length(); i++) {
        if (vowel(wordCap.charAt(i))) {
            vowels = wordCap.charAt(i);
        }

    }
```

The problem now is that the vowel method is not an applicable method type. It says it must be a char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to shorten that method for you ;)

Try something like this:

```
private static final char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
public static String translate(String word) {
    int start = 0; // start index of word
    int firstVowel = 0;
    int end = word.length(); // end index of word
    for(int i = 0; i < end; i++) { // loop over length of word
        char c = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i)); // char of word at i, lower cased
        if(Arrays.asList(vowels).contains(c)) { // convert vowels to a list so we can use List.contains() convenience method.
            firstVowel = i;
            break; // stop looping
        }
    }
    if(start != firstVowel) { // if start is not equal to firstVowel, we caught a vowel.
        String startString = word.substring(firstVowel, end);
        String endString = word.substring(start, firstVowel) + "ay";
        return startString+endString;
    }
    return word; //couldn't find a vowel, return original
}
```

What this snippet does, is iterate over every character in the word, storing the index of the first vowel in the `firstVowel` variable. Then, we get every character from `firstVowel` to `end`; and store it in `startString`. Then, we get every character from `start` to `firstVowel`; add "ay", and store it in `endString`. Finally, we concatenate these strings together and return them, resulting in the desired output.

We can test this with `System.out.println(translate("trees"));`

**EDIT:** Without array, as requested:

```
public static String translate(String word) {
    char a = 'a';
    char e = 'e';
    char i = 'i';
    char o = 'o';
    char u = 'u';

    int start = 0;
    int firstVowel = 0;
    int end = word.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        char c = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i));
        if(c == a || c == e || c == i || c == o || c == u) {
            firstVowel = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(start != firstVowel) {
        String startString = word.subString(firstVowel, end);
        String endString = word.subString(start, firstVowel) + "ay";
        return startString+endString;
    }
    return word;
}
```

*As you can see, arrays shorten things up quite a bit!*

If you're feeling pedantic about the `Arrays.asList().contains()` call, we could define our own:

```
public static boolean containsChar(char[] lookIn, char lookFor) {
    boolean doesContainChar = false;
    for(char c : lookIn) {
        if(doesContainChar = c == lookFor)
            break;
    }
    return doesContainChar;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot this is a little past my level though ahah, how would I do this without an array?

Comment: @T3rm3nator, you could manually assign each character like `char a = 'a';` `char b = 'b';` etc. and then loop over your word checking for each variable manually. However, I do suggest you get comfortable with arrays, as they make looping a lot easier, which shortens code. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: yes, it helps, its just I have not been taught that yet. so far this is what I have added.

Comment: Ah I can see the difference quite well. This makes me excited to learn about them...every assignment I get I feel like theres an easier way to do it, and then the next week we learn the easier way to do it. It gets on my nerves but I can see the usefulness to it. Thanks a lot for your input. It looks really helpful, I will be sure to upvote when I complete it!

Comment: @T3rm3nator, no problem. I'd like it if you learned something new tonight, as the old adage goes "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime." Your teacher/professor is doing the right thing by showing you how to do things the hard way, and then showing you how much time the easy way saves. Think of all the people who can "use" dreamweaver, but can't touch html code.

Comment: @T3rm3nator, I also missed the part where you want to check if the first letter is a consonant. If you'd still like to do that, it's as easy as `if(!Arrays.asList(vowels).contains(Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0)))` at the first line of the method. This checks if the first letter is not a vowel, ie a consonant.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `for` loop to iterate through the letters of each word until it finds a vowel. Example:

```
String wordCap = word.toUpperCase();
char vowels;

for (int i=0; i<wordCap.length(); i++) {
    if (isVowel(wordCap.charAt(i))) {
        vowels = wordCap.charAt(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Of course, I only used `isVowel()` for the sake of keeping the example concise. You'll have to identify it as a vowel the same way you did in your first `if` statement (or write an `isVowel()` method yourself).

For modifying the word, you'll also want to declare a variable to hold the index of the vowel. The previous section of code could be added to for this, like so:

```
String wordCap = word.toUpperCase();
char vowels;
int vowelIndex;
String newWord;


for (int i=0; i<wordCap.length(); i++) {
    if (isVowel(wordCap.charAt(i))) {
        vowels = wordCap.charAt(i);
        vowelIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then you could reference `vowelIndex` when modifying the word.

```
if (vowelIndex == 0) {
    newWord = word + "way";
} else {
    newWord = word.substring(vowelIndex) + word.substring(0, vowelIndex) + "ay";
}
return word;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot this is very insightful. So by using loops I wouldn't really need the else if's would I?

Comment: I don't think so. To be honest, I couldn't quite figure out what you were even trying to do with all those if statements, though I figured it was related to what the for loop I gave was for.